# Set auto-increments based on hospital ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My Company has multiple clients. Each client needs to have their own auto increment column.
For example, there are multiple hospitals that need to record their patients' records to my server. And each patient needs to have a reference number. Reference numbers are incrementing.

Here is what I want my table to look like

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|  user_id  | names     | ref_no    | hospital |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|    1      |cholo wao  |    1      |  TMJ     |
|    2      |royson ml..|    2      |  TMJ     |
|    3      |pascal va..|    3      |  TMJ     |
|    4      |mustafa s..|    1      |  MBE     |
|    5      |nassoro h..|    4      |  TMJ     |
|    6      |zunaida s..|    2      |  MBE     |
|    7      |hadija ma..|    3      |  MBE     |
|    8      |kulsum za..|    4      |  MBE     |
|    9      |zawadi ya..|    1      |  MSA     |
|    10     |khamis mo..|    5      |  TMJ     |
|    11     |saada hem..|    5      |  MBE     |
|    12     |mark zuck..|    6      |  TMJ     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

As you have seen above the `ref_no` only increment based on the last insert ID of a previous Hosptial. I have been told that using `MAX(hospital)` can cause danger as more than one row may be inserted at a time.

#### summary QN

> Which Query can I use to insert reference number based on the last ID of a particular hospital?

Comment: Why not use a GUID instead of auto-increment?

Comment: You can set the Databasefield "ID" to autoincrement. You just need to insert Data to generate an ID automatically.

Comment: @juergend can GUID identifies that this patient is from TMJ hospital and Increase the reference number based on what is last from TMJ... For Example, the Last reference number from TMJ is 5, how can this increase to 6

Comment: what about a prior query to find the last ref_no per hospital basis ? for example latest ref_no is select MAX(ref_no) where hostipal='MBE' + 1; before insert a new record

Comment: @Saber I just want to clear things that the  system should detect which is last reference number so it can increase

Comment: @Always Sunny what if two people run that query at the same time and they got 5. all will be added 5 as reference number

Comment: A GUID is not a sequencional number

Comment: @juergend how can I implement in  a sequential way

Comment: @Cholowao yes you are write that is a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen two solutions in SO about this, make a try

**1st one**

```
CREATE temporary table seq ( id int, seq int);
 INSERT INTO seq ( id, seq )
  SELECT user_id, 
   (SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM client c 
   WHERE hospital='TMJ') as seq 
  FROM client;

UPDATE client INNER join seq ON client.user_id = seq.id SET 
 client.ref_no = seq.seq;
```

**2nd one**

```
 INSERT INTO 
 client( names, ref_no, hospital )
'cholo wao',SELECT MAX(ref_no) + 1 WHERE hospital='TMJ','TMJ' FROM    
 client;
```